# ASP.NET Core self-contained compatibility?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

I have been playing around deploying my .NET Core application on several Operating Systems using self-contained and portable platforms.

As expected, this runs fine on Windows 8.1, Windows 10 and OSX.

I also have a 2008 Windows Server with IIS7 and this is causing a few issues. I have tried to run the self-contained executable but returns `procedure entry point kernel32.dll` error which apparently means that I have selected the wrong runtime in my `project.json` file.

Where can I get a list of compatible ASP.NET Core runtimes?

I believe portable .NET Core apps are **NOT** compatible with IIS7 as AspNetCoreModules requires IIS7.5, is this correct?

Comment: Mainstream support of Windows 2008 (not R2) ended a year and a half ago.  Extended support goes until 2020, but the fact 2008 isn't in mainstream support means that new products aren't going to support it.  You really should upgrade it to at least R2, though preferably the latest 2012 R2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The article *Publishing to IIS* on ASP.NET Core docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) says that Windows Server 2008 *R2* is required.